# How to make a recyclerview selections tags android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-selector

Sorry for this poor question, but as I'm new to android i need som help... does anyone know how to do this tite of Recycler view, or is any other way to this?
[image]

Comment: Those are called "chips". You can use them with the material design libraries: https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips

Comment: **THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!** @AlexanderHoffmann